# how to compare two input of type datetime before submitting

Tags: javascript, date

I am working on a web project using j2ee. anyway, in my jsp page I have a form containing two inputs of type datetime-local, and one of them must be greater than the other,it's like validating start and end datetimes, so I don't know how to make this test before submitting..I tried a javascript code in submit button onclick, I tried to make the input field of the second date empty if it is lower than the other,but it doesn't work. can anyone help me?

my form in jsp page

```
<form id="tab" action="AjouterMCorr" method="GET">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date Panne</label>
        <input required type="datetime-local" name="datePanne" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date Maintenance </label>
        <input required type="datetime-local" name="dateMaint" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="btn-toolbar list-toolbar">
        <button onclick="
             var dateMaint = new Date($('#dateMaint').val()); // or Date.parse(...)
            var datePanne = new Date($('#datePanne').val()); // or Date.now()
             if( dateMaint.getTime() < datePanne.getTime() )
                 {

                 document.getElementById('#dateMaint').value = '';
                  }
           " type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you explain what "doesn't work" means? Did you get an error? If not, what result did you get? It is important to give us all the information you can before we spend time on your question.

Comment: I would not make any of the date inputs empty, as instantiating a new Date() object with an empty value will cause that new Date object's getTime() value to be NaN.

Comment: Any reason you are not comparing the input field values directly? I think that should give you comparable/sortable values right away.

Comment: simply, nothing happens, I mean even if I delete the code in onclick, nothing change :/

Comment: @BenSewards  I make it empty because it's a required input, so when I click on submit, it won't insert thee values, and it won't pass until I put a right date, I didn't find any other solution. I just want to pass the submit button only if the dateMaint is greater than the datePanne. you understood what I am trying to do?

Comment: Note that not all browsers in use support input type date, so you can't guarantee that the string is a valid date. Also, parsing strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent) is **strongly** recommended against as native parsing is largely implementation dependent. Specify the format you want, provide an on–screen hint for it, then manually parse the value (a library can help but generally a 3 line function to parse and validate the string will suffice).

Comment: Oh, also, from within the listener, *this.form* will reference the form, and *this.form.datePanne* will reference the control with name *datePanne*. But anyway, the listener should be on the form's submit handler, not on the button since the form can be submitted without clicking the button.

Comment: The operation is subject to error; enclose your code inside a try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the Moment.js library recently, which supports comparison of the difference between dates on it's [Docs page](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/).

Example:

```
var start = moment($('dateMaint').val(), 'MM-DD-YYYY');
var end = moment($('datePanne').val(), 'MM-DD-YYYY');
if (end.isBefore(start)) { //stuff... }
```

You do need to be careful when parsing DateTimes in javascript as browsers don't always interpret time the same way.

Comment: Rather than "*interpret time the same way*" consider "*consistently parse the string*". Also, the selectors wont find the right elements.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple small things wrong with your javascript that prevented your form validation from working correctly. Let's go over the steps to fix this, and then view the jsfiddle link below for the example:

1. Your jquery selectors weren't targeting the actual inputs, as your date inputs didn't have the id (#) you were targeting, so instead, I changed the selectors to find the inputs by name.
2. Your onclick attribute on the submit tag should be abstracted to only include a function, and the actual logic should go in a nearby script tag below the form.

   3. Now that it's working and since you have the **required** attributes (keep in mind are HTML5 supported) on the date inputs, you shouldn't have to check if the values exist, but you can return false to prevent the form from submitting when 1 value is greater than the other.

**HTML**

```
    <form id="tab" action="AjouterMCorr" method="GET">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Date Panne</label>
    <input required type="datetime-local" name="datePanne" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Date Maintenance </label>
    <input required type="datetime-local" name="dateMaint" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="btn-toolbar list-toolbar">
    <button onclick="onSubmit()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">
  </div>
</form>

<script>
  function onSubmit() {
    var dateMaint = new Date($('input[name="dateMaint"]').val()); // or Date.parse(...)
    var datePanne = new Date($('input[name="datePanne"]').val()); // or Date.now()
    if (dateMaint.getTime() < datePanne.getTime()) {
      return false;
      console.log("test");
    }
  }

</script>
```

**Update**
Changed the form submit to the form element as other form tags could trigger a submit on the form.

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uugm9dgg/10/).

Comment: what exactly doesn't work about it? it prevents form submission when nothing is submitted and validates the 2 date inputs correctly..

Comment: whatever I put in the two dates, it accept the submission !

Comment: what browser are you on? And are you looking at the jsfiddle i provided? You should not be relying on "datetime-local" input type as most major browsers do not support it, seen here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: Based on the updated jsfiddle i provided, what is not working? Please provide a detailed response this time.